# using function directly on turtle library without making object of class Turtle()

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am using the turtle library and applying functions directly on it.
But I am little bit confused, why the code is working fine even when I didn't make it an object of class `Turtle()`.
For example, `turtle.color("red")`, `turtle.forward(100)` are working fine in the given code

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()

turtle.color("red")

tim = turtle.Turtle()
tim.color("yellow")

turtle.forward(100)
tim.backward(150)
screen.exitonclick()
```

Output:

[image: screenshot of output]

Comment: Hello, it's because of the [import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

Comment: The module contains loops that generate global functions that call each method of the `Screen` and `Turtle` classes, first creating a default object of that class if one doesn't exist yet.  See `_make_global_funcs()` in turtle.py if you want the details on how this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [turtle documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html):

> The turtle module provides turtle graphics primitives, in both **object-oriented** and **procedure-oriented** ways.
>
> The object-oriented interface uses essentially two+two classes.
>
> **The procedural interface provides functions which are derived from the methods of the classes [Screen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.Screen) and [Turtle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.Turtle)**. They have the same names as the corresponding methods. A screen object is automatically created whenever a function derived from a Screen method is called. An (unnamed) turtle object is automatically created whenever any of the functions derived from a Turtle method is called.
>
> **To use multiple turtles on a screen one has to use the object-oriented interface**.

Lets say we have a module called `bot.py`. Here is an example of a procedural-oriented script:

```
name = None

def greet():
    print(f"Hello {name}!")

def chat():
    print(f"So {name}, how are you today?")
```

And here is an example of an object-oriented script:

```
class Bot:
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name

    def greet(self):
        print(f"Hello {self.name}!")

    def chat(name):
        print(f"So {self.name}, how are you today?")
```

For the turtle module, both options are available.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. Can you explain in simple language?

Comment: @Sujal I added an example of object-oriented and procedural-oriented.